# How to let an dropdown accept only integers using angular schema forms

Tags: angularjs, angular-schema-form

this is the link to angular schema example
http://schemaform.io/examples/bootstrap-example.html
and I want a dropdown list to accept only integer values.Is there any way to do so.
Thanks for the Help!

Comment: in your schema definition, you should be able to just put `"type": "integer"` for the field.

Comment: @plong0 thanks it works